# LACP, sever 2012R2, qnap NAS & FAULT negotation

Tags: network-attached-storage, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, lacp

I've setting up a Windows Server 2012 R2 with hyperV services.

The VM's hard drives are in Qnap NAS model **TS-453S PRO**.
Between the server and the NAS, there is a D-link switch model **DGS-1210-10**.

I've try to configures all the networks to use the LACP teaming mode, but the server reports that the connection teaming is in state **"FAULT negotiation"**, but the connection works (at limited speed).

[Configuration of team server side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1eJk.jpg)

[Switch configuration: 
Group 1: 2xLAN from server; Group 2: 2xLAN from NAS /
NAS configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmGYa.jpg)

Sorry for the images, but with reputation < 10 I can insert only 2 links :(

How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you!